# Flash Builder 4.6 : Design view not working with flatspark theme

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

After switching to Apache Flex 14, I tried to implement the Flatspark theme by adding this kind of rules to my CSS :

```
s|Panel
{
    skinClass: ClassReference("flatspark.skins.PanelSkin");
}
```

To make the SDK work with Flash Builder 4.6, I changed the SDK description file. From here, everything's fine.

I was able to see the new theme, create component in the design view and edit already existing MXML files.

But after restarting Flash Builder, I've got this little icon in the design view :

[image: Design View not working with an error Icon]

I cannot see or edit an existing file.

The design view works again after removing the theme from the CSS rules.

Why did it works the first time and now only display this when I add a custom CSS rule to change the skinClass parameters ?﻿

Answer (score 0):

Design view has never really worked correctly for any use case that is even remotely complex.

This is why it was removed in the next version (Flash Builder 4.7).